# Sharing library or site in SharePoint without login to the account office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to share my library create on SharePoint Online. But I want to send only a **link** to this person and he can access to this library (this person don't have office 365 account).

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set up the SharePoint site for people who don't have Office 265 account. You can quickly and securely give such users access to either your Team site or SharePoint Online sub-sites by sending them an invitation through email. Here is the detailed description on how to do it:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-small-business-help/share-a-site-with-external-users-HA101850586.aspx

Comment: Yes Falak, you have right. I want to send only link, so the user need not to use Live Id, and I need not to send invitation to him.

Comment: The person you invite to the site receives an email that includes a link to accept the invitation. To accept the invitation, the invitee needs to provide an email address that is associated with a Windows Live ID, or, if they’re an existing Office 365 customer, a Microsoft Online Services ID. If they don’t have an email address or a Windows Live ID, they can create one for free. The external user can choose one of three types of email addresses to log in to the site; an email address that is associated with Windows Live ID, a Windows Live ID email address, or a Microsoft Online Services ID.

Comment: I know this work, but I want to need not any invitation. Share this library to external users without send any invitation (because I don't know all email address users that will be use this library).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. See a similar thread here: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/152/t/45501.aspx

Comment: That's a big shame Office365 is forcing people to at least have Live Email.